# How to disable MacOS X helper tool?

Tags: macos, whatsapp.app, auto-update

Every now and then some apps asks to auto update using the built in helper tool. **I am so tired of it.** They ask for privileged access.

Is there a way where I can disable that for all apps? May disabling this helper tool? I want to upgrade my apps manually.

In some apps (like in the one in the picture) I cannot disable auto update feature. It's a [dark pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern), there is no option for that!

[image]

If not, I will need to uninstall those awful apps.

Comment: Normally, apps should only ask once to install their Helper Tool. They will of course flag you to update the app itself whenever an update is available. This can be annoying when you want to crack on with work, but you can always cancel it, and then set aside some time to update things when more convenient.

Comment: I have this very same issue, macOS is so annoying these days.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to disable that one place for all apps.

Contrary to what you might think, it is not the case of one macOS helper tool. Instead it is each of these apps that comes with its own helper tool - different from the helper tools of other apps.

Some apps will function even when you remove their helper tool - some will not. But it will have to be done individually.

Comment: That is so annoying. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnJohnPichler: Yes, Apple's freedom of choice is so gratifying.

Comment: @Seamus Each program can choose to include a helper tool - it’s not one Apple imposed tool. It’s actually a case of Apple allowing developers the freedom to choose.

Comment: @jksoegaard: Yes, in this instance you're correct, but is it unreasonable to expect Apple to provide a *master switch* to disable them all? Maybe, maybe not. But  **Apple** does not allow its users to disable the continual nagging to update &/or upgrade their OS & Xcode. Apple also chooses to set the "perma-nag" option on `Garage Band` - an app I have not only never started, but when I agreed to the update to stop the nagging, I get a notice that it ***cannot be upgraded*** & nagging continues. Apple doesn't allow users to remove Siri. On & on; as JJP said, "annoying" - I totally agree.

Comment: What do you mean "in this instance" - this is the only instance that we're talking about here in this question. And yes, it would be unreasonable to expect Apple to provide such a master switch. That wouldn't make sense. I get that you have a strong belief that Apple is somehow an "evil dictator" that takes away choice, but right here you're actually advocating for being exactly that. Essentially what you're asking is that after Apple has said to developers "please make the best user experience for your users - you're allowed to run helper programs", you want Apple to then switch off all [...]

Comment: [...] those helpers, saying to the developers that "your opinion doesn't matter, we know best". It would break all sorts of programs, we would see user's reporting issues to developers "I disabled your program, and now it doesn't work", etc. I can't see how that would be beneficial. If you ACTUALLY know what you're doing, then it is easy to disable all these helpers tools in one go. If you are a software developer, you can do this - and know what consequences to expect in terms of broken programs.

Comment: I get also that you do not like to upgrade your programs - however every professional in computer security would tell you that updating your programs is essential to keeping not only your own computer and network safe, but also others. Systems that are not updated should be cut off from the Internet and kept safe that way - that also solves the nagging about updates. If you are a software developer and understand why it is important to update your software, and still decides that you do not want to update - you can actually disable the nagging. But I totally get why you wouldn't give [...]

Comment: [...] home users this choice. Please also remember that you have the choice of not using macOS. You could simply use another system. However, most if not all other popular choices also made decisions for you. That's what makes a system attractive. If you're running Debian Linux with a Gnome desktop, there's options you can't change, there's choices you cannot undo, there's things you cannot avoid, etc. The same applies if you're running Windows 11. Ofcourse, if you are a software developer, you can mold the software to your liking on any system - but if you think there's some system out [...]

Comment: there that allows every user to have readily available configurations options for every thing imaginable - then you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Okay - it's been a month now... I didn't respond earlier as you seemed quite upset by my comment, but I did have a couple of points to make in closing: The "instance" that prompted my comment is the ceaseless nagging to upgrade, and I feel that Apple has over-reached badly in this "instance". Some of your points re updating software are well-taken, but your logic wrt "home users" strikes me as *elitist*. I don't think I'm alone in my opinion, and I fail to see why being a "software developer" gives one much greater insights here. [...]

Comment: After all it was software developers that shipped Catalina with an open `root` account. It was software developers that sent Siri recordings without notification, and on and on. Your attitude seems to be that "home users" are a bunch of hapless boobs who should have no choices or prerogatives, and be banned from owning a computer if they don't follow the `diktats`. Gee whiz, @jksoegaard - that sounds a lot like the vaccination policies in some countries - and we see where that is going. Your arrogance is showing, sir.

Comment: I don’t think you make much sense. I’m not talking about software developer as any type of “elite”. It was a short way of saying “people that know how to look things up on Google and configure their system accordingly”. Of course some home users can do that as well. Then by all means disable software updates. However the majority of users would be ill served by disabling updates. If you think you know your way about a computer and you think you can understand the consequences of not updating - then simply disable the update notifications and don’t upgrade.

Comment: Your analogy with vaccinations policies seems so out of place though. You’re perfectly allowed to be mistrusting. I don’t think I’m the arrogant one though.

Comment: By the way: your argument that Apple has overreached “in this instance” doesn’t really make any sense. These update windows are not prompted by Apple - it’s the third party application developer that has decided they are there. Apple does not provide an automatic “built in helper tool update system” at all.